# I want to update my conference_room_booking table by checking time slot availability on booking date or upcoming date

Tags: sql, lookup

I have two table room_detail and conference_room_booking

```
room_detail       conference_room_booking
-------------     ------------------------
room_id PK        room_booking_id PK
room_name         room_id
no_of_seat        user_id
                  date
                  from_time
                  to_time
                  room_status
                  creation_time
```

User already booked room and  wants to update conference_room_booking
table by checking availability of time slot(eg-2-4,5-7,9-10) on that day or
other day, and can change room_name also.

Condition: user should not book the past date or time

How to do that in sql query? What portion can be done in sql query?
Please help.

Comment: what do you have?

Comment: you can assume any data in both table

Comment: i meant.. do you have any scripts that you are working at?

Comment: i don't know how to write this query. i dint write any code for it. i am asking to write query

Comment: you've got to try it first dude.. we are not spoon-feeding people here. we let them learn by correcting

Comment: haha k bro.... can you tell how to do it... not asking code ...just process

Comment: will ask you in better way.. how to search and update in one query

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334741/1385774

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```